# WPF AutomationID vs. Name for identifying UI elements on Ranorex

Tags: wpf, automation, ranorex

for the application I'm running automation on - I noticed that there was a problem that some of the elements cannot be found via view spy.  These elements do not have names nor Automation ID.  I suggested adding one of these to all elements, which would you recommend for my purpose and what are the differences between the two?  I just want to be able to locate elements as quickly and as efficiently as possible.  I am fairly new to WPF automation testing as I traditionally come from a web automation background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it doesn't matter which attribute is used as long as it is unique.